# I am using Spring Social framework .Getting org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException with Proper access token

Tags: android, facebook, spring-social

I have got the access token from Android native application.I tested through Graph API debugger and its active for next two months.Created Facebook template with the same access token.When i try template.isAuthorized it returns true.But when i try to access template.userOperations it through the following error please help.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V not found
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleFacebookError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:89)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:415)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:213)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchConnections(FacebookTemplate.java:222)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchConnections(FacebookTemplate.java:216)
```

Comment: What is the code that throws this error

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  String accessToken="XXX";
  FacebookTemplate facebook= new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
  if(facebook.isAuthorized()) {
   System.out.println("Authorized");
    UserOperations userOperations = facebook.userOperations();
    FacebookProfile facebookProfile = userOperations.getUserProfile();
    String birthDate = facebookProfile.getBirthday();
    String firstName = facebookProfile.getFirstName();
  } else {
   System.out.println("Not Authorized");
   
  } instead of XXX i have provided accesstoken from my native android app.

Comment: Could you put that in the body of your post; more readable than a comment

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace is a little misleading, because you're actually looking at `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` in the class `org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException`.

More specifically, it complains `method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V not found`, or in other words: the constructor that takes a string parameter doesn't exist in the aforementioned class.

To me that sounds like you're running a rather old version of Spring, most likely a 1.0.x release. I.e. compare the constructors for version 1.0.3 and 1.1.0:

1.0.3: [`public MissingAuthorizationException()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/MissingAuthorizationException.html)

1.1.0: [`public MissingAuthorizationException(String providerId)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/social/MissingAuthorizationException.html)

Your problem should be solved as soon as you switch over to a version of Spring that does have a string-parameterized `MissingAuthorizationException` constructor.

// edit: the constructor was changed to include the provider ID in October 2012. [This commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/commit/a1ba10cfc5da5322178a00abfb15d1a13a4d8e80), to be precise.

Comment: Hi @MH Thanks for the immediate response.Here is the complete stacktrace :::: Authorized
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate handleResponseError
WARNING: GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/me" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V not found

Comment: @Rajarajeswari: That doesn't change my answer. :) I wouldn't worry too much about the json error message. The key is in the last line.

Comment: @Rajarajeswari: Glad to hear. Please remember to tick the answer if you feel it helped you solve the problem and you think it may be helpful for others too.